# Continuously read the appended data from a file in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am continuously monitoring a file using Kafka and want to read only the appended data from a file and push it to the Kafka producer. Here's what I am trying to achieve:

```
    val fileName = "abc.txt"
    try {
      val command = "tail -f " + fileName
      val p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command)
      for (line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines) {
        val message = line + "\n"
        val producerRecord = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("topicName", message)
      producer.send(producerRecord)

    }
    producer.close()
   }catch {
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
     }
```

tail -f works in Java but not working in Scala. I am getting following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tail": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

How can I achieve this in Scala?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Why do you create the `p`, the "tail" process, and never use it? The error says that `The system cannot find the file specified`. Have you checked to see if the program is running in the proper directory where the file can be found?

Comment: That's my question is how to use that "p" in scala as it is a Java Implementation. And yes the directory path specified does have the file in it.

Comment: Btw this code is already written in scala. But exception handling done is in java style.

Comment: by Java Implementation I mean to say that I have used the java libraries.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use the regular Java methods to consume the output of the `p` variable.

Comment: I was looking for a better way to do it by not using "tail -f" approach. Anyways I get it working. Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should you use Kafka connector for that. Kafka connector will load the data from your file to specified topic. Whatever changes will be there in the file, it will directly reflect to Kafka topic. And from that topic, you can consume data. [Refer](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/07/10/apache-kafka-connect-example/)

Comment: And what if the file is getting continuously appended? Will it be able to read only the appended data?

Comment: It will reflect all changes in topic whatever happens in file. You can explore about it. Kafka connect will surely simplify your use case.